# Consider tossing a coin five times. What is the probability of getting the same $result$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider tossing a coin five times. What is the probability of getting the same $result$, on the $first \text{ two }$ or $last \text{ two }$ tosses?

---

The size of the sample space is $2^5.$

Let $E$ - first two tosses are same.

Let $F$ - last two tosses are same.

---

$P(E) + P(F)$

$|E| = |F| = 2^5$

$\text{_ _ _ _ _}$ Given 5 tosses, toss 1 can be heads or tails $\binom{2}{1}$. Toss 2 must be whatever toss 1 was. (1). Toss 3,4,5 can be any $\binom{2}{1}$*$\binom{2}{1}$*$\binom{2}{1}$.

So we have:

$$\frac{\binom{2}{1}(1)\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{2^5} = \frac{16}{32}$$

Similarly, for last two tosses same, it is also $$\frac{16}{32}$$

---

But this equals $1$, and $100\%$ is definitely not right ... what did I do wrong?

Comment: You need to subtract the probability of getting both $E,F$.

Comment: Side note:  it's much easier to compute $P(E)$, say, then you are making it.  The first toss is whatever, and the second matches it with probability $\frac 12$, so $P(E)=\frac 12$.  the other tosses are irrelevant.

Comment: You lost me.  $P(E\cup F)$ is the probability of both $E$ and $F$ so, yes...you need to consider the scenarios in which first two match AND last two match.  $E,F$ are independent events so $P(E\cup F)=P(E)\times P(F)=\frac 14$.

Comment: Yeah but are there two scenarios to consider? For example, first two tosses are SAME, last two tosses are SAME: TT|H|HH or HH|T|TT ... thats one scenario . Is another scenario when first two AND last two tosses are same (4 of one kind) : TT|H|TT or HH|T|HH ? is that something different?

Comment: I'm not understanding the distinction you are proposing.  The scenarios covered by $E\cup F$ are:  $TTxTT,TTxHH,HHxTT,HHxHH$  where "$x$" can be either $H,T$.  Thus there are $8$ such scenarios and, just to check, $\frac 8{32}=\frac 14$.

Comment: Okay then nevermind, if they are covered then it is 1/4. Your correct. Thanks!

Comment: Note:  for problems like this, if there is confusion...just write everything down.  If you use the "$x$" notation as I did there are only $16$ states to write out, but even if you write all $32$ out properly it isn't that bad and looking over the whole list really should dispel most doubts.

Comment: @lulu: How about TTxyx, etc.?

Comment: @BruceET  Thanks....for some reason (brain fatigue) I was systematically writing $E\cup F$ when discussing $E\cap F$.  That is, the scenarios I was talking about were those in which BOTH $E$ and $F$ occurred.  Good catch.

Comment: @lulu: I've got much experience with brain fatigue, esp typos and misreading problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $E$ and $F$ are independent and each has probability $0.5$.

So the answer is $0.5+0.5-0.5^2=0.75$

Comment: Did u calculate 0.5^2 ? Or you just got that number?

Comment: $P(E \cap F) = P(E)P(F)$ by independence.